# Is it possible to "pretty print" my input integral in Mathematica like Wolfram|Alpha does?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting

With Wolfram|Alpha, if I enter:

```
Integrate[r^3, {t, 0, 2Pi}, {r, 0, 2}, {z, r^2, 4}]
```

Wolfram|Alpha will pretty print my input like so:

[image]

Which is very readable, and I can easily check to make sure I entered in my bounds and integrand correctly. Were as if I entered that formula straight into Mathematica, it just spits out the answer and I have to manually inspect my raw input for typos.

So, my question is: **Is it possible to nicely display formulas in Mathematica without using Wolfram|Alpha?**

I want a way to convert my raw input "`Integrate[r^3, {t, 0, 2Pi}, {r, 0, 2}, {z, r^2, 4}]`" into a more human-friendly form.

(The problem with calling Wolfram|Alpha from Mathematica all the time is that it is slow, sometimes times out, requires internet, and is often much more noisy than I need.)

Comment: Select cell -> Right click -> Convert to -> TraditionalForm

Comment: Also, typing `Esc` + `int` + `Esc` enters $\int$, which I've always found to be far more convenient than using the drop-down menus.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Could use intt instead of int to get a complete template for the integral with placeholders for the bounds.

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalTypesetting.html, especially the Learning Resources part.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like

```
heldint = HoldForm[Integrate[r^3, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 2}, {z, r^2, 4}]];
int = ReleaseHold[heldint];

Row[{heldint, " \[LongEqual] ", int, " \[TildeTilde] ", N[int]}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! I think I'll end up using `// HoldForm // TraditionalForm` as my preferred way to verify my input

Comment: Is there any way to convert those 3 lines of yours into a single function? So I could do something like `Integrate[...] // Pretty` and see exactly the output you showed

Comment: Got it: `SetAttributes[Pretty, HoldAll]; Pretty[fn_] := (heldint = HoldForm[fn]; int = ReleaseHold[heldint]; Row[{heldint, " \[LongEqual] ", int, " \[TildeTilde] ", N[int]}] // TraditionalForm);`

Comment: Yes. You could do `int = fn;` instead of `int = ReleaseHold[heldint];`.

Answer (score 16):

[`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html) looks nice but it also incurs additional complexity in handling expressions.  If you attempt to evaluate a `TraditionalForm` cell you will be asked if you wish to interpret it as input, and the equivalence is not always complete.  Fortunately *Mathematica* is quite cabable of displaying formatted integrals in [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm.html).

If you merely wrap your expression in [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) and evaluate it you will get:

```
Integrate[r^3, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 2}, {z, r^2, 4}] // HoldForm
```

[image]

You can convert the expression in place without evaluation by selecting it and using menu **Cell** > **Convert To** > **StandardForm** which under Windows has the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.  Example:

[image]

Note the active syntax highlighting which is not present in `TraditionalForm`.

Comment: IMO this is the answer OP was looking for. To be honest I didn't read the original question carefully and just provided a way to mimic Alpha's output.

Answer (score 7):

*Mathematica* 10 introduced a new set of functions that can help with this:

```
    Inactive[Integrate][r^3, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 2}, {z, r^2, 4}]
```

[image]

Or, obtaining same output:

```
    Inactivate[Integrate[r^3, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 2}, {z, r^2, 4}]]
```

And then:

```
    Activate[%]
(* 32 Pi/3 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

wiki answer. All the above solutions are fine, but I think Maple does this much simpler and I thought to show how Maple does it, may be future versions of M can adopt this. (in some way, can't use the same Upper/Lower trick ofcourse, since M commands already start with UpperCase)

In Maple, there is what is called the Inert form. Command that starts with upper case, do not evaluate.  This way one can verify the command by typing `Int` instead of `int` then to actually evaluate, type  value() on the form.  Here is an example

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see how simple it is.

**update:**
Thanks Karsten comment, Mathematica in V10 seems to have adopted this using Inactive (I never used this command myself actually before...too many commands, too little time). But it seem to do what Inert in Maple does:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Very nice. I think I'll start using this more.

Comment: `Inactive` seems to be the adoption made in v10.

Comment: @Karsten7.: Yes, but will probably also work for v11, v12 and further on

Comment: @Karsten7.: I would be happier if it had a "pretty" input like the output! :) Does it have such a thing?

Comment: @H.R. I'm not sure what you mean, but you can try 1) Using one of the Palettes 2) Marking the input, right click and choose Convert To StandardForm or TraditionalForm 3) Using [InputAliases](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAliases.html) (for example Esc dintt Esc).

Comment: @Karsten7.: Let me clarify myself. For example, active integration has a command form like `Integrate[f[x],{x,a,b}]`. Also, it has a pretty form which we can achieve by `Esc+dintt+Esc`. Does **inactive** integration has a pretty form like the latter case.

Comment: @H.R. I'm not aware of one and I don't see what the practical application of a pretty input form for an inactive integration would be, as one could just evaluate it in place (since it's inactive).

Comment: @Karsten7.: Pretty inputs are just for better readability. Also, inactive commands have lots of applications. You may check the inactive page in Mathematica documentation. As an example, sometimes you just do not want to evaluate anything but just to obtain a general formula. :)